# How to create a iframe that appears when you click a button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I would like to have an iframe inserted into a column div on my web page when someone clicks on it. How do I make this possible? When someone is just viewing the page the iframe will be made invisible, but when a button is clicked the iframe will be made visible. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Give your iframe a class like `hidden iframe` then add the following JavaScript before the closing `</body>` tag:

#### Your Frame

```
<iframe src="..." other-iframe-stuff="" class="hidden iframe">

</iframe>
```

#### JS

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $(".your-toggle-btn").click(function(){
      $(".iframe").removeClass("hidden");
   });
});
</script>
```

Your button should have a `your-toggle-btn` class and define the following CSS styles:

#### CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: okay so do i actually insert the iframe into the html of the page

Comment: Depending on your use you could hide the iframe with JavaScript instead of css, this would mean it's still accessible to users without JavaScript

Comment: @SamOpoku Please check out @AJReading's comment to make the iFrame visible for people who have disabled JavaScript on your website.
Also it's good practice to keep in mind that not everyone wants javascript to be executed. The code would stay the same except you will remove the `hidden` class from your iFrame & add the following line of code:
`$(".iframe").addClass("hidden")` right after your first $(function{ & before the $(".your-toggle-btn") :)

Answer (score 0):

Give your iframe and button classes or data-attributes, so you can reference them.

Then create an event that displays the iframe on button click, using jQuerys hide() and show() functions. It's important that the iframe is visible to start with if you wan't the site to function when javascript is turned off.

```
<script>
$(function(){
   var $button = $('.iframe-opener'); // or [data-iframe-opener]
   var $iframe = $('.iframe'); // or [data-iframe]
   $iframe.hide();
   $button.click(function() {
       $iframe.show();
   });
});
</script>
```